# Change (e-mail) button colors in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, css, laravel, html-email, laravel-5.7

What is the best way to change the success, error and primary colors in Laravel 5.7?

I have the email.blade.php via `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

```
...
{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    switch ($level) {
        case 'success':
        case 'error':
            $color = $level;
            break;
        default:
            $color = 'primary';
    }
?>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
...
```

The template uses the `'success'`, `'error'` and `'primary'` to color the button, but where can I change the values for them?

Comment: Laravel uses Bootstrap 4, either choose a predefined class (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) or overwrite the existing classes in your `app.scss`

Comment: @kerbholz Adding styles like `$primary: #ff9900;` doesn't seem to work for the mail template. The scss gets properly compiled to public/css/app.css (the color is set to `.btn-primary` for example). but when I send a mail, the button still has it's default blue color. Any clue on what goes wrong or how to style the email.blade.php?

Comment: `.btn-primary { background-color:red; }` should change the color of _all_ `btn-primary` elements to have a red background-color (also those on your website though). Just make sure you add that _after_ bootstrap gets imported.

Comment: @kerbholz But also in the mail templates? They don't seem to use the public/css/ap.css

Comment: Oh ok, never worked with emails in Laravel ;). I think you should `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#mail-notifications) to publish all relevant mail resources. In `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes` edit `default.css`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This is the best and correct way from

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/7

(I'll extract) - Run

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail, this will create vendors/html folder in your views directory.`

Then create a new theme file at

`/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/my_theme.css`

Then in

`config/mail.php`

Set new theme

```
        'theme' => 'my_theme',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

Now you can set your own CSS and create any new button colours.

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url, 'color' => 'success'])
View Group
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 4):

Just run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`, this will create vendors/html folder in your views directory.

Then edit the `/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css` file and change `.button-primary` class.

Additionally, you have access to all the HTML code of each mail notification component as well if CSS changes are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the best way is to create ColorHelper class?

```
class ColorHelper {

    public static function level($level) {
        if(method_exists ( $this , $level )) {
            call_user_func($level);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function success() {
        return '#00FF00';
    }

    public static function error() {
        return '#FF0000';
    }

}
```